# Random varible defined from another ($Y:=\left | X \right |-1$)

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

Given a PMF of $X$

$$p(x)=\left\{\begin{matrix}
0.1, & x=-4, \\ 
0.2 & x=-1\\ 
0.6 & x=1\\ 
0.1 & x=2\\ 
0 & else 
\end{matrix}\right.$$
Find $\mathbb{P}(X \geq 0.8)$, $\mathbb{E}X$, var$(X)$ and sd$(X)$. Furthermore, find the mean and pmf for $Y:=\left | X \right |-1$.

I have found the firs 4 solutions $\mathbb{P}(X \geq 0.8)=0.7$, $\mathbb{E}X=1$, The varians to be $17/5$ and thus the sd to be roo square root of that answer.

Now for the last 2: Would this mean that the PMF's entries of $Y$ would just correspond to the aboslute value of the discrete r.v $X$ minus 1? Would you have to compute the mean from the start even though we just calculated the expected value?

Comment: ould this mean that the PMF's entries of Y would just correspond to the aboslute value of the discrete r.v X minus 1? Yes. But take take into account that $|1|=|-1|=1$

Comment: $P[X\ge 0.8]$ is correct, but E[X] and Var[X] are not correct. For the last two, $|X|$ can be 1, 2 or 4, so $Y$ can be 0, 1, or 2. Find the probability that $Y$ is equal to each of those values (that's the pmf) and then find the mean.

Comment: @JohnL Oh that is my bad. I got it to be expected value equal $1/5$.

Comment: @callculus so the remaining probability for $P(Y=1)$ must be $0.2$.

Comment: @mathstudent23 Not really. Y=1 does not exist. You should firstly calculate all y-values with the formula $y=|x|-1$. To keep the overview a table is useful with the column names $x$ and $y=|x|-1$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** To start make a table of the transformed x-values.

$$\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|c|} \hline x &-4&-1&1&2  \\  \hline y=|x|-1 &3&0&0&1  \\  \hline \textrm{prob.} &0.1&0.2&0.6&0.1 \\ \hline  \end{array}$$

Now you can write down the pmf of y, $P(Y=y)$. What is $P(Y=0)$ for instance? Then you calculate the expected value and the variance as usual.

Comment: yes it is correct.

Comment: Meant 2 and not -2 for the last probability*

Comment: @mathstudent23 That I was wondering. The rest is correct. But you have to say that $P(Y=0)=0.8$ So the part  $0 \cdot 2/10 + 0 \cdot 6/10$ ist just $0\cdot P(Y=0)=0\cdot 0.8$

Comment: @callculus Yes of course since it is just one element and not two that are weighted for $Y$

Comment: @mathstudent23 You got it.

Comment: $p_Y (y) = \left\{\begin{matrix}
0.8 & y=0, \\ 
0.1 & y=2,\\ 
0.1 & y=3 \\ 
0 & else
\end{matrix}\right.$ This would be the pmf in the case of this.

Comment: @mathstudent23 That´s correct.

Answer (score 1):

1. For the pmf question: basically yes. But you should notice that $X$ takes 1 and -1 which will be the same after taking absolute value. So $P(Y=0)=p(1)+p(-1)=0.8$.
2. You have to calculate the mean from start. Mean is a linear functional of random variables, so it couples pretty well with linear transformations. However, the absolute value is not linear, so you can not tell directly from mean of $X$ the mean of $|X|$. Actually this can be even not well-defined: see [Cauchy distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_distribution). Intuitively we should have $``\mathbb{E}X=0"$(and we do, in the sense of Cauchy principal value), but the integral $\mathbb{E}|X|$ diverges.

Comment: so the remaining probability for $P(Y=1)$ must be $0.2$.

Comment: why? x can be -4

Comment: Ah okay so $P(Y=0)=0.8$ but why is that? I see that $Y=(-1)-1$ and $Y=(1)-1$ both equal $0$ since it is the absolute value of the r.v $X$. But where did you get that $0.8$ figure from?

Comment: it is just the sum of p(1) and p(-1), from the pmf of x.

Comment: Yes so p(-1) is the remaining 0.2

Comment: why is that? it is already in P(Y=0). See @callculus's answer for details.

Comment: Yes see my comment. I think I got it now on his comment.